# Java Garbage Collector for stack

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is garbage collector responsible for stack removal?

Does it also deallocate memory for static/constant variables?

example:

```
class A
{
   void fun(){
   int x = 100;
   static int y = 200;
   final int z = 300;
   }
}
```

Is all three variable's memory deallocated when function gets completed?

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile, as you can't declare static variables. It's not clear what JavaScript has to do with this, either... are you aware that JavaScript and Java are entirely different languages?

Comment: How is `java-ee` related?

Comment: Also, in Java you can't force garbage collection, you can only request it. You never know when the JVM will do it.

Answer (score 2):

The garbage collector is responsible for orphan objects on the heap.

Have a look at this Oracle tutorial [Java Garbage Collection Basics](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html). It explain the GC basics.

Answer (score 2):

Static fields will not be eligible for garbage collection as long as the class they live in is loaded. And according to [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html):

> A class or interface may be unloaded if and only if its defining class
>   loader may be reclaimed by the garbage collector.

Comment: What you say is true as long as the class does not de-reference the object by setting the static field to null.

Answer (score 0):

Basically garbage collection deallocates memory for all objects that are no longer referenced by any other object in the JVM. So it doesn't matter if it is a static or instance field or a local variable.